# going for the next youtube video in my iphone app

Tags: objective-c, youtube

i'm developing an iphone app which can play youtube links using a web view
Every things fine. but except it goes to the next video  automatically. is thr any way to stop this.
Here is my code.

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/wh0ZK5QJMWk"; //http://www.youtube.com/embed/wh0ZK5QJMWk 
NSURL *url = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlAddress] autorelease];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Thanks

Comment: What is defining the "next" video? Are you attempting to play a playlist?

Comment: thanks for the reply. no im not playing a play list . i only gv a single url . so in the app whn i click on the play button it plays nicely. after  the play is finished. once i click on done button on youtube player . it shows the next video. this should stop

Comment: Have a look at your web view delegate methods. Are they doing anything unusual? What is the "next" video anyway? The next video on your profile? The next related video?

Comment: i think related video here is the [link] (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MliyDPW7JHo)